# Implications of divergence of $1/\zeta(s) $ at 1/2

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, prime-number-theorem

$1/\zeta(s)=\sum_{n>0}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$ where $\mu$ is the Moebius function.

This series is known to converge for $s\ge 1$ and diverge for $s\le 1/2$.
Its convergence is unknown if $1/2< s< 1$ (convergence in this interval is essentially the Riemann hypothesis). Convergence at 1 is equivalent to prime number theorem.

Does divergence at 1/2 have similiar implications?

Comment: Accurately speaking, it is the analytic continuation, instead of convergence and divergence

Comment: Divergence at 1/2 means that the partial sums of the Mobius function cannot exhibit more than square-root cancelation.  Or equivalently that the error term in the prime number theorem cannot be substantially smaller than $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @Lucia: Perhaps you should post your comment as an answer, as it seems to resolve the question.